# How temporarily to "disable" currently handled exception returning by sys.exc_info()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Inside some except block I'm releasing resource (that should be released with no exception), but that resource's release function uses `sys.exc_info()`. Is there any way to temporarily mark there's no exception handled now? I created solution that just substitutes `sys.exc_info` function, but it looks not very reliable. May be any better way exists?

```
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def no_exc_info():
    f = sys.exc_info
    sys.exc_info = lambda: (None, None, None)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.exc_info = f

try:
    try:
        raise Exception()
    except:
        with no_exc_info():
            # here I want sys.exc_info to return (None, None, None)
            print('1', sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise
except:
    print('2', sys.exc_info()[0])
```

Output (as I want):

```
1 None
2 <class 'Exception'>
```